# AspxCallback is not updating information

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback

I have an AspxCallback control that is supposed to update textbox text when i click the Button. But nothing happens when I click the button. 
Here is my sample code for the test:

**C#:**

```
 protected void callback_Callback(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallback.CallbackEventArgs e)
{
    txtTest.Text = "Text for Textbox";
}
```

**ASP.NET:**

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="CLICK"     OnClientClick="callback.PerformCallback(); return false;" />
   <br />
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Width="200" Height="25"></asp:TextBox>
   <dx:ASPxCallback ID="callback" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="callback" 
    oncallback="callback_Callback">
   </dx:ASPxCallback>
```

Comment: Why not just use the OnClick rather than the OnClientClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Your problem resides on the fact that the TextBox is not inside a CallBack Panel.
The way a callback works is like an ajax call that can update only the **Ajax enabled** so to say controls. Those controls can be put inside a callback panel for this exact reason.

```
<dxcp:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="ASPxCallbackPanel1" runat="server" Width="223px"     BackColor="#FFFFC0" ClientInstanceName="callbackPanel1" Height="78px" oncallback="callback_Callback">
        <PanelCollection>
            <dxp:panelcontent runat="server">
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="CLICK" 
                OnClientClick="callbackPanel1.PerformCallback(); return false;" />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Width="200" Height="25"></asp:TextBox>
            </dxp:panelcontent>
        </PanelCollection>
</dxcp:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

I think this will solve your problem. Now your code will update the TextBox properly.